# Django model design - ManyToManyField or ForeignKey: opted option

Tags: django, django-models

To deal with the 2 options (*ManyToManyField or ForeignKey*) in a project, to be honest, I use the first that comes to my mind.

Let's say we have the following models where a *Project* can have multiple *Assignments*.

**1st option:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = #

class Assignment(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name='assignments')
```

> With ForeignKey, when deleting a project, all the assignments related will be also deleted (That's perfect)

**2nd option:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    assignments = models.ManyToManyField("Assignment")

class Assignment(models.Model):
    # fields
```

> With ManyToManyField, when deleting a project, if I need to delete all the assignments related, I have to use *signal*

**From the point of view of performance and clarity, what is the option opted for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just one element in your relation you should use ForeignKey that as the same of OneToManyField

If you need many elements from same class related with your object you should go with ManyToMany...

Simple comparison, in django admin ForeignKey render just one select, so you can choice only 1 element by time... while ManyToMany Widget you can select multiple options

Comment: So in my case, what is the option that you suggest?

Comment: Keep in mind that manytomany logic each assisngment can be used by other projects... so if you delete ir will affect all other projects

Comment: if this assisntment only interact with only 1 project, you should go the first way... if other projects can use the same assigment you should go the second

Comment: An assignment can only be assigned to one Project, A Project can have one or multiple assignments

Comment: Go the first way

Comment: upvoted your answer, I will accept it later! Thank you very much.